# Find month in time range

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, select

I do have a MySQL table with records containing beginning and ending date as a timestamp.

> id(int) | dtBeg(timestamp) | dtEnd(timestamp)

I do try to select record which have a given month within the time range.

For example:

> id(int) | dtBeg(timestamp) | dtEnd(timestamp)
>
> 1 | '2013-06-20' | '2013-08-20'
>
> 2 | '2013-07-20' | '2013-09-20'
>
> 2 | '2013-07-25' | '2013-07-28'

Records happening in June: 1

Records happening in July: 1, 2, 3

Records happening in August: 1, 2

Records happening in September: 2

Currently I don't know what might be a good approach to handle the dates range, so I could extract months. The only solution which comes to my mind is way to complicated and I am sure that there is an easy and smart way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For such comparisons, I like to convert date times to "months since time zero".  That you, you can do the calculation with just arithmetic.

For your query, this looks like:

```
select t.*, year(compdate), month(compdate)
from t cross join
     (select date('2013-07-01') as compdate) const
where year(compdate)*12+month(compdate) between year(dtBeg)*12 + month(dtBeg) and
                                                year(dtEnd)*12 + month(dtEnd);
```

Here, I've put the `compdate` in a subquery.  That way, if you want to check for multiple months, you can just add rows to the table:

```
select t.*, year(compdate), month(compdate)
from t cross join
     (select date('2013-07-01') as compdate union all
      select date('2013-08-01')
     ) const
where year(compdate)*12+month(compdate) between year(dtBeg)*12 + month(dtBeg) and
                                                year(dtEnd)*12 + month(dtEnd);
```

This form would work in many SQL dialects.  You can do something similar with MySQL specific functions by using `date_format()`.

```
select t.*, year(compdate), month(compdate)
from t cross join
     (select '2013-07' as compdate union all
      select '2013-08'
     ) const
where compdate between date_format(dtBeg, '%Y-%m') and date_format(dtEnd, '%Y-%m)
```

Comment: Thank you, your solution works perfectly. Now I have to understand why :).